# What's the difference between קסת הסופר and מנחת שי?

Tags: jewish-books, torah-reading, safrus

I am a Torah reader. I am always interested in learning about the nuances of how trope is used as well as the rules about how the Torah scroll is written, and the relationship between the writing activity and reading / chanting.

In various questions here, as well as speaking to a few people, two books have been mentioned קסת הסופר and מנחת שי. I forgot what each book delves into and what the differences are with these two works. Please describe / summarize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keset HaSofer, by R [Shlomo Ganzfried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Ganzfried), discusses the laws of writing as a Sofer STaM. Topics include: how to make Kosher parchment, shapes of the letters, intent when writing, what sorts of corrections are permitted, prohibition of erasing God's name (among other things). Online at Hebrewbooks.org [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/38188).

Minchat Shai, by R [Yedidya Nortzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedidiah_Norzi), discusses the correct text of Tanakh. Topics include: differences in spelling, vocalization, and cantillation between various manuscripts and/or printings of Tanakh. In particular, he works to decide what the correct version should be for us. Online at Hebrewbooks.org [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14036).

Comment: Keset hasofer chelk beis http://hebrewbooks.org/41271 is probobly what the OP was refering to, not chelek alef.